# Searching a large string in Database

Tags: sql, postgresql, cockroachdb

So I have a table in which one of the columns is used to store data of type string which usually has 10000 characters. When trying to match a particular string it takes a lot of time operationally. Is there any way to reduce it ??

Comment: You can use Postgres's plentiful full text search capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to optimize select query like this

```
select *
from tbl
where field_code ilike '%text%'
```

use gin index

more info here https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/exploring-postgres-gin-index